# OpenCV Background substraction using Absdiff

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I've been working about a program to detect hands by background substracting.
I have tried to save the first frame of a camera as Background and substract with current frame, but it appeared that they have different brightness somehow.
I've tried it several times and I dont have and light changing, what can be the problem?
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJgNl.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkA0O.jpg)

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "Camera.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int LAPTOP_CAM = 0;
    const int LIFECAM = 1;
    const int MAX_FPS = 25;
    Camera cam(LIFECAM);
    Mat backGround;

    cam.TakeShot();
    cam.MirrorImage();

    cam.getFrame().copyTo(backGround); //Deep Copy
    imshow("Background", backGround);
    Mat diff;
    while (true) {
        cam.TakeShot();
        cam.MirrorImage();
        absdiff(cam.getFrame(),backGround , diff);

        imshow("Result", cam.getFrame());
        imshow("Diff", diff);

        cam.Set_FPS(MAX_FPS);

        if (waitKey(1) == 27)
            break;

    }

}
```

here is "Camera.cpp":

```
#include "Camera.h"
Camera::Camera()
{
}


Camera::~Camera()
{

}
Camera::Camera(int camNum)
{
    VideoCapture cap(camNum);
    _capture = cap;
}
void Camera::TakeShot()
{
    _capture >> _frame;
}
void Camera::Set_FPS(int fps)
{
    if (fps > 25)
        fps = 25;
    else if (fps < 1)
        fps = 1;
    _capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, fps);
}
Mat Camera::getFrame()
{
    return _frame;
}
void Camera::MirrorImage()
{
    flip(_frame, _frame, 1);
}
```

Comment: I assume your camera uses some kind of auto-gain, like most cameras. When it is first activated (by your program), it will gradually adjust the gain until the image is at a decent brightness/contrast level. Can you try sleeping for a couple of seconds before taking the background shot?

Comment: That helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There should always be subtle lighting change and absolute subtraction would hardly work. If you have to use absolute different, you might want to threshold `diff`.

However, you should look into some background subtraction algorithm. [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html#gsc.tab=0) has some built-in methods: MOG2, KNN.

Also, you can detect hands using skin (color) detection.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from exposure compensation in the camera (which could be the problem in image2 — the foreground object changes the overall scene brightness), you should also look at the effect of flickering if you're using fluorescent (and possibly LED) lighting; since the light turns on and off at your AC line frequency, and your camera shutter speed could be higher than that, it's possible that in one image it catches the light "on" and in another it's "off".

Answer (score 0):

i agree to Quang Hoang using background subtraction algorithm will be better.
but if you want to do it manually then you must copy last frame to background.

could you try by adding a line `cam.getFrame().copyTo(backGround);` as seen below

```
while (true) {
    cam.TakeShot();
    cam.MirrorImage();
    absdiff(cam.getFrame(),backGround , diff);

    cam.getFrame().copyTo(backGround); // add this line

    imshow("Result", cam.getFrame());
    imshow("Diff", diff);
```